# OpenSearch Javascript Client No or Bad response

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, opensearch

I am trying to integrate [OpenSearch Javascript Client](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/javascript/index/) with Serverless Node application.

I have setup the client as follows

```
const client = new Client({
    ...AwsSigv4Signer({
        region: AWS_REGION,
        service: 'es',
        // Example with AWS SDK V2:
        getCredentials: () =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                // Any other method to acquire a new Credentials object can be used.
                AWS.config.getCredentials((err, credentials) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        logger.info('credentials', credentials);
                    }
                });
            }),
    }),
    node: 'mydomain.url', // OpenSearch domain URL
});
```

And used as

```
export async function search(): Promise<any> {
    logger.info(`open search connection => ${client.transport.connectionPool.getConnection()?.status}`);
    let result;
    try {
        result = await client.search({ index: 'opensearch_dashboards_sample_data_ecommerce'});
        logger.info(`search response ${JSON.stringify(result.body).slice(0, 200)}`);
        return result.body;
    } catch (error: any) {
        logger.error('open search client error', error);
    }
    return result?.body;
}
```

However I am not getting logs after the await search call. `open search connection` logs as `alive`

Also when I try to connect to local OpenSearch Cluster using docker.

```
const client = new Client({
    node: `http://admin:admin@localhost:5601`,
})
```

above same function returns error

```
{"body":"","statusCode":302,"headers":{"location":"/app/home","osd-name":"d2bf50a79df9","cache-control":"private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate","set-cookie":["security_authentication=Fe26.2**a7a9f2cd499adba847e8b7b4712a2b304ecc5f0783628c90c1394141a8cc805d*-rKqsQ7n_BAVWq0t01RLFQ*ArbJO8TFB1m_ZKSYOKKo02SgOzuC7mKz0XmfOLmiOdJ217Y1I2QGMeXBL0pcFzBcKLwn-3i-3vfomGQdewyrYS2EqN8d69oL5qBLcUSwVaLkOUGFiU5LMe_aLBcQoObQNK-GcBH4qH-mwUe4uDBYtqGtjv1VVFY6AjeNI5sCoIXxLhylIZRqw5csO4KHwMeu9tXPGlSxm-xpI9gz_Pc0Yg**67d8efb5627180bd7631dc9b1dc6d235ed4c19949c2cde277a0926bdabd12856*HbvmzN14lC8SMcTfI1R6-KVvsg3df_d9_eJs3YEB6Mo; HttpOnly; Path=/"],"content-length":"0","date":"Fri, 20 Oct 2023 07:35:16 GMT","connection":"keep-alive","keep-alive":"timeout=120"},"meta":{"context":null,"request":{"params":{"method":"GET","path":"/","body":null,"querystring":"","headers":{"user-agent":"opensearch-js/2.4.0 (darwin 21.6.0-arm64; Node.js v16.19.1)"},"timeout":30000},"options":{},"id":3},"name":"opensearch-js","connection":{"url":"http://localhost:5601/","id":"http://localhost:5601/","headers":{},"deadCount":0,"resurrectTimeout":0,"_openRequests":0,"status":"alive","roles":{"data":true,"ingest":true}},"attempts":0,"aborted":false}} 
2020-08-21 02:20:15: [error] - open search client error Response Error {"name":"**rror","meta":{"body":{"statusCode":"**04","error":"**ound","message":"**ound"},"statusCode":"**04","headers":{"osd-name":"**9df9","content-type":"**tf-8","cache-control":"**date","set-cookie":["**th=/"],"content-length":"**60","date":"** GMT","connection":"**live","keep-alive":"**=120"},"meta":{"request":{"params":{"method":"**ET","path":"**dZGN","headers":{"user-agent":"**9.1)"},"timeout":"**0000"},"id":"**4"},"name":"**h-js","connection":{"url":{"href":"**601/","origin":"**5601","protocol":"**ttp:","username":"**dmin","password":"**dmin","host":"**5601","hostname":"**host","port":"**01","pathname":"**/"},"id":"**601/","headers":{"authorization":"**aW4="},"_status":"**live","roles":{"data":"**ue","ingest":"**ue"},"agent":{"_eventsCount":"**2","defaultPort":"**80","protocol":"**ttp:","options":{"keepAlive":"**ue","keepAliveMsecs":"**00","maxSockets":"**56","maxFreeSockets":"**56","scheduling":"**fo"},"freeSockets":{"localhost":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null[{"_host":"**host","_readableState":{"highWaterMark":"**6384","flowing":"**ue","reading":"**ue","constructed":"**ue","needReadable":"**ue","autoDestroy":"**ue","defaultEncoding":"**f8","dataEmitted":"**ue"},"_eventsCount":"**6","_writableState":{"highWaterMark":"**6384","defaultEncoding":"**f8","allBuffers":"**ue","allNoop":"**ue","constructed":"**ue","autoDestroy":"**ue"},"_sockname":{"address":"**.0.1","family":"**v4","port":"**5189"},"_peername":{"address":"**.0.1","family":"**v4","port":"**01"},"bytesRead":"**18","remoteAddress":"**.0.1","remoteFamily":"**v4","remotePort":"**01","localAddress":"**.0.1","localPort":"**5189","localFamily":"**v4","_bytesDispatched":"**42","bytesWritten":"**42"}]]},"keepAliveMsecs":"**00","keepAlive":"**ue","maxSockets":"**56","maxFreeSockets":"**56","scheduling":"**fo","maxTotalSockets":"**nity","totalSocketCount":"**1"}}}},"stack":"ResponseError: Response Error\n  at onBody (/Users/abhimanyupatil/Desktop/repos/portal-backend/node_modules/@opensearch-project/opensearch/lib/Transport.js:425:23)\n  at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/abhimanyupatil/Desktop/repos/portal-backend/node_modules/@opensearch-project/opensearch/lib/Transport.js:340:11)\n  at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)\n  at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n  at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)\n  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)"}
```

Need help integrating the same. Not sure if I am missing anything.